# Ubuntu oracle jdk issues when trying to install disutils for Cython

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

I am trying to install disutils to use Cython which requires python3-pip according to this:  https://superuser.com/questions/1319047/cant-install-virtual-interpreter-in-pycharm-in-linux

So when I try to `sudo apt install python3-pip`, everything looks okay until I get to:

```
Setting up oracle-java11-installer-local (11.0.5-1~linuxuprising0) ...
Before installing this package,
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,

E.g.:
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 installed oracle-java11-installer-local package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Except when I enter `java -version` everything looks okay:

```
java -version
java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

and my `/var/` folder where the `tar.gz` for the JDK is supposed to be copied to, I think it looks fine when I enter `-ls`:

```
fontconfig.Ubuntu.properties  javaws-wrapper.sh
jar.binfmt                    jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

I'm concerned about these two lines above:

```
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
```

I have the 11.0.5 tar.gz in my downloads folder but have not attempted to install it since the lines before say to use 11.0.4 which seems to be installed.

```
please download the Oracle JDK 11 .tar.gz file
with the same version as this package (version 11.0.4),
and place it in /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local,
```

If there is a way to just get disutils installed so I can use Cython please post an answer.  Otherwise, please tell me what is happening with JDK.

I originally downloaded the 11.0.4 JDK because I read that using it would resolve some of Pycharm IDE's hanging issues (which it did for the most part).

I found a `.deb` package for disutils here:  https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-i386/python3-distutils_3.6.8-1~18.04_all.deb.html

Should I try installing this with a `dpkg -i` command and just ignore whatever is happening above with the jdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello**,

It has nothing to do with `python3-pip`, it has however something to do with the new **Java 11 version**. Please follow the following steps (as in the other post where you posted this link) and update the Java first:

I've had **the same issue**.

When you try to run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` it will automatically try to update the Java if a newer version is available. In my case let's say from **11.0.4** -> **11.0.5**.

If you add the JDK from Oracle (after download) to `/var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/` it **should work**.

You don't have to uninstall it...(I mean the oracle-jdk11-installer-local, it works just fine).

Please let me know if you still have this issue.

Comment: I did something similar and now it seems fine.